# Is there F# Interactive for Linux on .NET Core, without using Mono?

Tags: linux, f#, .net-core

I'm able to build and run F# projects with .NET Core, but unable to use or see F# Interactive with it. Is it on the roadmap somewhere?

I'm using Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: It is better to look and ask question here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/f-and-net-core-roadmap-update/ (look for F# Interactive) As it is a bit off-topic, I afraid.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

dotnet core 3 preview 3 [supports](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-preview-3/) F# interactive as a pure .NET Core application:

```
dotnet fsi --readline
```

Comment: Alo important to finish lines with `;;` took me a while to read the doc until that point.

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is, but it's hidden in a deep directory.

I have the following script in my $PATH, with name `fsi`, to find it and launch it:

```
#!/bin/sh

dotnet=/usr/bin/dotnet
fsi=/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/*/FSharp/fsi.exe

if ! [ -f $fsi ] 2>/dev/null; then
    echo ERROR Cannot find fsi.exe or more than one is present
    exit 2
fi

exec $dotnet $fsi "$@"
```

Result:

```
$ fsi

Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 10.2.3 for F# 4.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> 1+1;;
val it : int = 2

>
```

With this, you can uninstall Mono and the old `fsharp` package.

Comment: How does the * in fsi=/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/*/FSharp/fsi.exe work? I understand it resolves to the version, but what are the rules? Its a bash feature right?

Comment: @citykid To tell you the truth it's kind of a misuse. In Bash, and most other shells, `*` resolves to *all* the names in the `sdk` directory that contain an `FSharp/fsi.exe` file. So if you have more than one SDK version installed, it won't work :-P

Comment: thx, that way it fits better with my knowledge ;-) its cool to have dotnetcore fsi running. i struggle with vscode and ionide now.